# How to count unique users based on other columns in a function?

Tags: excel, vba, count, duplicates

[image]

I have a data set with this set up, where I have varying number of weeks, hosts, and users (what I will be focusing on).

What I need to do is to be able to count the **unique** users per week per host.  I will be updating this list weekly so I would like to use a formula that I can put into a macro to automate it instead of doing a pivot table.

What I have so far:

```
SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Active_Users_Master!$A:$A;"9";Active_Users_Master!$D:$D;'C:\Users\wra\Desktop\host.xlsx'!host1))
```

The above counts the number of users per week 9, and compares the host name to a named range I've created in another excel.  SO it does everything but it doesn't count unique users which is the last step.  I'm also not looking to simply remove duplicates because I would like to ultimately keep all information stored and not lose any data.

Looking at the picture I've attached, I would want "Jones" to appear only once in my Week 9 count of host 1.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  If you can help write a VBA script, that would be even more amazing!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ListUnique()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim key As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each c In Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            key = c.Value & "|" & c.Offset(, 2).Value & "|" & c.Offset(, 3).Value
            .Item(key) = c.Row
        Next c

        Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        For Each key In .keys
            Rows(.Item(key)).Hidden = False
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great to hide all the duplicates, but it doesn't change the value after inputting my formula.  Is it possible to tell excel to only calculate based off non-hidden rows if I select $A:$A for example?  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I don't get you. You wrote "What I need to do is to be able to count the unique users per week per host", which is precisely what my code does. Are you throwing in a new request?